# I get Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound

Tags: chef-infra

I have a standalone Chef server. I uploaded the cookbook using knife and added to the run list of the node. on the node's chef client I ran sudo chef-client and i get Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound Cookbook pilot_sec_update not found. Get this whether I specify the recipe or run the cookbook default

Comment: Any idea what pilot_sec_update is - is that one of your identifiers? This question is the only hit for it on Google.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hard thing to debug in one fell swoop so you are probably better off asking on Slack but roughly 1) check that the cookbook upload worked via `knife cookbook list` and `knife cookbook show` 2) make sure if your cookbook has any dependencies, you uploaded those too 3) make sure both your `knife.rb` and the node's `client.rb` are aimed at the same Chef Server URL.